# A Central Limit Theorem simple example

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, fractions, central-limit-theorem

A disscusion in the book: Let $(X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ a sequence of i.i.d random variables such that $\mathbb{E}[X_n]=60, \operatorname{Var}[X_n]=25$. Let $S_N= \sum_{i=1}^NX_i$. By the central limit theorem we get $\frac{1}{5\sqrt{N}}\overset{D}{\rightarrow}N(0,1)$. I don't understand why does the next equality hold:
$$
\\  \mathbb{P}[55<{1\over N}S_N<65]=\mathbb{P}[-\sqrt N<{S_N-60N\over 5 \sqrt N}<\sqrt N] \
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following statements are equivalent:

- $55<\frac1{N}S_N<65$
- $55N<S_N<65N$
- $-5N<S_N-60N<5N$
- $-N<\frac{S_N-60N}5<N$
- $\frac{-N}{\sqrt N}<\frac{S_N-60N}{5\sqrt N}<\frac{-N}{\sqrt N}$
- $-\sqrt N<\frac{S_N-60N}{5\sqrt N}<\sqrt N$